# Points in polygons using R tree spatial indexing and geopandas

Tags: python, shapely, geopandas, r-tree

Context:
I have two CSV files. One has 5 million points and the other has 3 million points that make up polygons of districts in the UK. I need to find out how many points fall inside each district. What I have so far is two geodataframes one with polygons and one with points. Everywhere I look points to this tutorial using R tree spatial indexing: https://geoffboeing.com/2016/10/r-tree-spatial-index-python/.

Problem:
I do not understand how to implement this with multiple polygons, and get a result of the district name with the count of points that fall within.

Comment: I think you can use the spatial join function `geopandas.sjoin` to do this, which will make use of an rtree index under the hood.

Comment: Have tried this, but as I have so much data it takes too long. I need something more efficient.

Comment: Coding a custom version might not necessarily faster, since `sjoin` is already using an rtree index (you have a lot of data). But if you want to get help to have a custom version, it might be useful to provide a small reproducible example creating some data and showing the expected result.